# Is there a convention for the ordering of terms in the dot product of a vector with the gradient of a vector field? My left is another man's right

Tags: tensor-calculus, conventions, notation, vector-fields

Note: I use $\left[\dots\right]$ instead of $\left(\dots\right)$ to indicated function arguments.  I use $\left[\![\_,\_\right]\!]$ to signify a commutator.  And I tend to use bracketing where others leave them implied.  It has payed off well, so I'm not going to change that practice.

I just went through my notes and converted all $\mathfrak{v}\cdot\nabla\left[\mathfrak{w}\right]=v^{i}\partial_{i}w^{j}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}$ to $\nabla\left[\mathfrak{w}\right]\cdot\mathfrak{v}=\partial_{i}\left[w^{j}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}\right]v^{i}$.  So, by my newly established rules, $\mathfrak{v}\cdot\nabla\left[\mathfrak{w}\right]\equiv\delta_{ij}v^{i}\partial_{k}\left[w^{j}\right]\hat{\mathfrak{e}}^{k}=v_{i}\partial_{k}\left[w^{i}\right]\hat{\mathfrak{e}}^{k},$ in orthonormal coordinates.  My reason is that it is consistent with the conventions I use for dyadics, and is consistent with the ordering in the matrix expression:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\partial_{1}w^{1} & \partial_{2}w^{1}\\
\partial_{1}w^{2} & \partial_{2}w^{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v^{1}\\
v^{2}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

My notes are based on sources such as [Theoretical Physics, By Georg Joos and Ira M. Freeman](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486652270.html), which is over half a century old.  My adaptation is extremely different from what Joos and Freeman present. Joos used my original ordering, which I found very confusing.

I was unaware that contemporary authors even used the dot notation in conjunction with the gradient of a vector field, if they even use the gradient of a vector field, as such.

Then I immediately started taking notes on this little gem of a presentation: [Lie derivatives, forms, densities, and integration John L. Friedman.](http://www.ictp-saifr.org/schoolgr/Lecture0Friedman.pdf).  Much to my disconcertation, Friedman appears to use the conventions that I just abandoned.

Is there an established convention for relative placement of the operands in the dot product of a vector with the gradient of a vector field?  Is there a good reason for that convention?

I will observe that my newly adopted practice makes the cross product a bit tricky.

Comment: Might this be better for math stack exchange?

Comment: That's a good question.  I'm really interested in conventions used by physicists.  Mathematicians often used different notation from what physicists use.  Sometimes with good reason.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an established convention for relative placement of the operands in the dot product of a vector with the gradient of a vector field? Is there a good reason for that convention?

Taken from [Arfken and Weber:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123846544)

Suppose $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ are vectors (or more generally, tensor rank 1 tensors). The dot product that you request is (vector notation to index notation)

$$ \vec{v} \cdot \nabla \vec{u} \Rightarrow  (v_{i}) \cdot (\nabla \vec{u})_{jk} = v_{j} (\nabla \vec{u})_{jk} = v_{j} (\partial_{j} u_{k})$$

where $k$ is a free index meaning it is not summed over, and [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is used.
Typically, in physics, the quantities being dotted are kept separate so that it's clear what is being summed over, and it is implicitly written in some well defined basis.

Comment: Typically vectors are treated as contravariant. That is a $\begin{pmatrix}1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ tensor. So $\nabla\vec{u}$ is a $\begin{pmatrix}1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ tensor. Regardless of the index the contraction is performed on, contracting this tensor with a vector will result in a rank 1 tensor.  You have too many free indices in your result.

Comment: Woops! Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the answer, and hope it's more clear.

Comment: Arfkin (2nd Ed., 1970) does contract as you indicated: $\vec{v}\cdot\nabla\vec{u}=v^{i}\partial_{i}r^{j}$. Unfortunately, his example isn't very illuminating, since $\vec{r}$ is his position vector. So the gradient is the identity matrix, thus the dot product is symmetric. Expression $\delta_{ij}v^{i}\partial_{k}u^{j}=\nabla\left[\vec{u}\right]\cdot\vec{v}=\nabla\left[\vec{u}\cdot\underline{\vec{v}}\right]$, where $\underline{\vec{v}}$ means “$\vec{v}$ held constant”. I just reverse the order of the dot product.  Both are "correct".